# How do I localise the default value of attribute in a Core Data Entity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, localization

If I was creating an entity with a non-optional string attribute called, say, "name", I would put "Untitled" as the default. How could I localise this default value?

I could subclass the entity and and use `NSLocalizedString` in `awakeFromInsert` to do this. But I was wondering if there was another way.

Edit:

If this is the only way, then I'm fine with it. Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using -[NSEntityDescription attributesByName]. This will give you back an NSDictionary of NSAttributeDescription objects. You can then pull the one you want and use -[NSAttributeDescription setDefaultValue:] on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think awakeFromInsert is the only way

Answer (score 1):

You can localize most aspects of a managed object model, including entity and property names and error messages.  See here: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW13

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already seen that. But that doesn't show how to localise the default value for a property. In my example it would be localising "name" rather than "Untitled"